# Application Pool Identity seemingly running as network service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I've run into an issue managing our dev IIS instance and an MVC 3 web application. The issue is that when I try to connect to the database from the IIS machine via one of our website I get the error: Login failed for user . Where  is the name and domain of the server IIS is running on. The IIS server and SQL Server are on two different machines. I have read multiple questions on SO and other sites and it said to run under application pool identity, which we are doing. We have a user for the database that is tied to the application pool identity.

The site was operating as expected yesterday but after a server reboot it seems to have caused this issue. I have checked everywhere and there is not an area that would cause this to run under NETWORK SERVICE or LOCAL SERVICE. I've been banging my head on this problem all day and was hoping that there was some solution that I have missed.

Comment: Does your SQL Server Log show the login name coming from IIS when the connection fails?

Comment: @seagulledge Unfortunately I don't have access to those logs as the dev machine accesses the prod DB for authentication